# Inject laravel paginator class into another class

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I have:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')
        ->paginate(15);

// do some work on $products etc...
// now because of works done on $products the pagination data is
// is not available on $products anymore
```

and it works just fine, now for the API response we have a separate independent class which gets the results and makes it ready for the API output, so smth like:

```
return ApiResponse::generate($products);
```

now in `ApiResponse` class, I want to access the pagination data! and that's the problem.

I can get current page with:

```
$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath();
```

but how I can access other pagination data like total pages etc.

P.S: I don't want to create a custom paginator class, I want to access the current instantiated pagination class in another class. how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Simplest solution is keep copy of $products (instance of LengthAwarePaginator) lets say $product_pagination and send both to ApiResponce::generate($products, $product_pagination). Without knowing work done on $products class, its hard to say other solution

Comment: I know that and that's I have already implemented. but I just wanted to know how I can use the instantiated paginator class in another class...